# Getting Unknown Characters in Data-frame result

Tags: r, encoding

I created a script which working on data from SQL server and this data has a names of several items in Arabic & English language and i get Unknown Characters and (???) in Data-frame result As in [image]
And i tried to cjhange the encoding to "UTF-8" by using `DBMSencoding=utf-8` but i get the same result. Any one can help to solve this problem?
this's my code:

`

```
dbConnection <- "Driver={SQL Server};Server=.;Database=****;Uid=******;Pwd=****;DBMSencoding=utf-8"
con <- odbcDriverConnect(connection = dbConnection)
Orders <- sqlQuery(con, "SELECT 
                   DOC.ID AS [Transaction]
                   ,CASE
                   WHEN DOCD.ServiceItemID IS NOT NULL 
                   THEN dbo.RemoveNumericCharacters(CONVERT(NVARCHAR (MAX),SRI.Description))
                   WHEN DOCD.StockItemID IS NOT NULL 
                   THEN dbo.RemoveNumericCharacters(CONVERT(NVARCHAR (MAX),STI.Description))  
                   END AS Item
                   ,CASE
                   WHEN  DOCD.ServiceItemID IS NOT NULL
                   THEN 'ServiceItem'
                   WHEN DOCD.StockItemID IS NOT NULL
                   THEN 'StockItem'
                   END AS [ItemType]
                   FROM Sales.Sls_Documents DOC
                   INNER JOIN Sales.Sls_DocumentDetails DOCD
                   ON DOCD.DocumentID = DOC.ID
                   LEFT  JOIN Sales.Sls_ServiceItems SRI
                   ON SRI.ID = DOCD.ServiceItemID
                   LEFT JOIN Warehouse.StockItems STI
                   ON STI.Id = DOCD.StockItemID
                   WHERE CASE
                   WHEN DOCD.ServiceItemID IS NOT NULL 
                   THEN SRI.Description
                   WHEN DOCD.StockItemID IS NOT NULL
                   THEN STI.Description
                   END IS NOT NULL")
Orders$Item <- as.character(Orders$Item)
```

`

> > sessionInfo():  R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) Platform:
> >     x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build
> >     16299)
> >
> > Matrix products: default
> >
> > locale: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LVS0.png) LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
> >     LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United
> >     States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           [5]
> >     LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

Comment: Please type `sessionInfo()`  and paste the part about "locale" into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved This Problem With to steps:

1. I Used the `odbc` Package and assigned the `encoding` argument of the `dbGetQuery` Fun to `"Windows-1256"`
2. Set the `LC_ALL` Of `Sys.setlocale` to 'Arabic'
   And after doing this tow steps i Solved this problem 
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

you are using r-studio to display the data.frame? If so i made the experience, that sometimes special characters are not correctly displayed in the r-studio viewer but are correctly saved in the data.frame itself.

To check if your DF saves the values correctly - could you call your data-frame "DF" via the console in R-Studio, so it is printed out in the console itself - i found out that, in my case at least, there the coding of the character vars was displayed correctly.

So in conclusion this might just be a viewing "artefact" of r-studio.

If not, maybe a recoding of values after the import from sql in R is needed - but here i have not enough experience. Maybe this may help: [Link to base-R converter](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/iconv.html)

Best regards

Sebastian

Comment: Yes I'm using r-studio to display my result, but i tried also Visual Studio and i get the same issue, and i tried to view my result in the console but i get the same issue.

Comment: Ok - hmm then there are some other options - i have no experience with sql-databases but, and i say this with all caution, maybe recoding the character in sql before importing it may solve the problem. OR recode the the colums which are named "row" and "col" in your final DF. What kind of language your system uses? Can you try the following command? sessionInfo in R?

Comment: can you help to solve my problem after editing my Question ?

Comment: i tried to convert the encoding of my data by  `iconv` But there's no thing changed. `Encoding(Orders$Item)` i get "Unknown" For all my items even after converting  them to "UTF-8"